# Java Object Serialize With Nested ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

Curious if anyone may know of a way to serialize a Java object containing a nested ByteBuffer to a JavaScript TypedArray or ArrayBuffer.

Say I have an object that looks like:

```
class Sample {
     String getId() {}
     ByteBuffer getData() {}
}
```

I am familiar with being able to serialize the `Sample` class itself to an ArrayBuffer using Jackson. However, with Jackson converting the object to String/JSON it converts the `getData` property to a standard array.

I'm hoping there may be a way to serialize the `Sample` class and the inner `getData` property to an ArrayBuffer as well.

Answer (score 0):

JSON has no concept of an ArrayBuffer so you can't serialize to one.  You will have to determine what Jackson is outputting(It looks like a Base64 String) for a ByteBuffer and write your own deserializer in Javascript.

Comment: Yep, I was more so looking for perhaps another library or alternative way to send an object down to the client with the ByteBuffer as maybe a TypedArray or ArrayBuffer